# How to pass a Window Handle to a sub-process?

Tags: windows, winapi

I am working on a special project with an unusual design.

In my application/process, I will create a sub process to do some work. In my process, I need to get the feedback from sub process. I want to pass the Windows handle of my application/process to this sub process, so I am post message from this sub process.

How can I pass Window Handle to sub process? My sub process is an command line application without Window UI and with the main function like this:

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
```

Should I pass Window Handle to the main function? How?

Thanks

Comment: Command line application with winmain? Really unusual design. Why window handle want pass? HWND?

Comment: If you want HWND. GetConsoleWindow is your friend. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683175%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Just use a command line argument.  Cast the HANDLE to DWORD (okay in 64-bit too) and generate a string from that.  Do be careful with that handle, there are not that many things you can do with it safely out-of-process.  Like any window message that requires passing a pointer in wparam or lparam, those pointer values are not valid in the other process.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Window handles (HWNDs) are global to the system so you can just print the handle as a decimal number into a string buffer, pass it as a string on the command line when you spawn your sub-process with CreateProcess, and call _wtoi() or similar to convert the string back to a handle again.

Comment: If, for some reason, you don't want to use a command line argument, one (rather less elegant) alternative is an environment variable.

Comment: Is this documented in MSDN or just an implementation detail?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a named mutex (global), so both processes could access it,
   and take it.
2. Spawn the second process. It should wait for the mutex
   to be freed.
3. You can then pass the window handle using any Inter-Process Communication method; the easiest one may be [Shared Memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Just write the duplicated handle into shared memory.
4. Release the  mutex, so that second process could grab it.
5. Read the handle from the shared memory. It is now safe to use it.

The whole mutex manipulation is only to make sure second process will not read from shared memory before anything is written there.

(thanks to @JonathanPotter for comments)

Comment: Window handles are not normal kernel handles and cannot be passed to DuplicateHandle, etc. They are global to the system, not local to a process.

Comment: @JonathanPotter looks like you're right: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9110/Inside-Windows-Handles . Thanks, I'll edit the answer to match that.